# How to convert PDF to CSV with tabula-py?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, tabula

In Python 3, I have a PDF file "Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf" with 6,041 pages. I'm on a machine with Ubuntu

On each page there is text at the top of the page, two lines. And below a table, with header and two columns. Each table in 36 rows, less on the last page

At the end of each page, after the tables, there is also a line of text

I want to create a CSV from this PDF, considering only the tables in the pages. And ignoring the texts before and after the tables

Initially I tested the tabula-py. But it generates an empty file:

```
from tabula import convert_into

convert_into("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", "test_s.csv", output_format="csv")
```

Please, does anyone know of another method to use tabula-py for this type of demand?

Or another way to convert PDF to CSV in this file type?

Comment: try `import tabula` and `tab = tabula.read_pdf("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", encoding='latin-1')` Does it throw an error? if not, run `print(tab)`. Is it also empty?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's still empty (None)

Comment: tabula seems not to find the tables inside the pdf. Without having the pdf it's hart to tell why (on my pdfs tabula works grat). Maybe you could set `guess=False` and specify the `area` and/or `columns` (see options docs) or give `pdfquery` a try (https://github.com/jcushman/pdfquery) or see where "raw strings" can get you (e.g. with PyPDF2)

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at the documentation (https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py). But how do I find the area where the table is? My PDF is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P8kF0gUOVls6sOGed4R0C2PlVF5RFtU6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do I need a PDF editing program to find the coordinates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I've found the issue: you have to set `spreadsheet=True` and keep utf-8 encoding:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", encoding='utf-8', spreadsheet=True, pages='1-6041')
```

In the picture below I tested it with just the first page (because your file is huge):

[image]

You can save the DataFrame as csv afterwards:

```
df.to_csv('otuput.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

### Edit:

Ok, the error could be a java-memory issue. To make it faster I added the `pages` option. And there also was an encoding problem, so `encoding='utf-8'` added to the csv export. 
If you keep running into the java-error, try parse it in chunks, e.g. `pages='1-300'`. I just did all 6041 (on a 64GB RAM Machine), it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you! I then tried to do so: 
import pandas as pd

import tabula

tab = tabula.read_pdf("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", encoding='latin-1', spreadsheet=True, pages=all, header=0)

tab.to_csv('file_ready.csv', index=False)

Comment: But I had this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not builtin_function_or_method

Comment: Sorry, I think there were missing quotes on 'all'

Comment: Yes, or remove `pages` it from the options, so: `df = tabula.read_pdf("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", encoding='latin-1', spreadsheet=True)`

Comment: tab = tabula.read_pdf("Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf", encoding='latin-1', spreadsheet=True, pages='all', header=0)

Comment: I got this error message: CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', '/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/intercept/seguranca/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabula/tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', '--lattice', 'Ativos_Fevereiro_2018_servidores_rj.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think there are some issues in the pdf itself (on some pages). I'll run the loop to see which, but its slow on my machine.. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. There is something very strange, every page here has error messages

Comment: Hmm... yeah, thats strange. I'm on page 100 and until now I'ts fine, no errors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167837/discussion-between-ilja-and-reinaldo-chaves).

Comment: I keep getting "unexpected keyword argument: Spreadsheet"

Answer (score 4):

**Converting PDF to CSV with tabula-py**

```
from tabula import convert_into
table_file = r"ActualPathtoPDF"
output_csv = r"DestinationDirectory/file.csv"
df = convert_into(table_file, output_csv, output_format='csv', lattice=True, stream=False, pages="all")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

```
convert_into(pdfPath, outputCSV, output_format='csv', pages='all', lattice=True, area='[1.0,1.0,10.5,40.2]')
```