# Converting PDF to CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pdf, tabula

I have a 36 page pdf that I’m wanting to convert into a csv. The file has rows of names and columns of attributes. I’m using tabula and this is my code that will convert the first page the pdf to a csv. But when I try to include more pages, it gets messy and doesn’t execute properly. So how can I readjust my code to get all 36 pages of my pdf into a csv?

```
import tabula 

file = "data.pdf"

pdfData = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages =1)

output = tabula.convert_into(file, "converted.csv", output_format="csv", pages =1 )

print(output)
```

Comment: Checkout this page, maybe it can help - [How to convert PDF to CSV with tabula-py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560486/how-to-convert-pdf-to-csv-with-tabula-py)

Answer (score 1):

##### Try something like that if it helps:

```
import tabula 
file = "data.pdf"
all_data = []
for page in range(1, 37):
    pdf_data = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages=page)
    all_data.append(pdf_data)
final_data = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)
final_data.to_csv("converted.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pages ='all'`

```
import tabula 

file = "data.pdf"

output = tabula.convert_into(file, "converted.csv", output_format="csv", lattice=True, stream=False,  pages="all" )
```

link to docs:

https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html

https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/